# Как узнать что все объекты нажаты?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть объекты `div` с `id`. Как узнать что все объекты нажаты?

```
document.getElementById("keranim").addEventListener("click", ker());
document.getElementById("menanim").addEventListener("click", men());
document.getElementById("womenanim").addEventListener("click", women());
document.getElementById("flameanim").addEventListener("click", flame());
document.getElementById("keranim").addEventListener("click", eye());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var ids = ["keranim", "menanim", "womenanim", "flameanim"];
var clicked = [];
document.querySelectorAll("#" + ids.join(",#")).forEach(
  i => i.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (!clicked.includes(this.id)) {
      clicked.push(this.id);
      if (clicked.length == ids.length) {
        console.log("all have been clicked");
      }
    }
  }
));
```

```html
<button id="keranim">keranim</button><br/>
<button id="menanim">menanim</button><br/>
<button id="womenanim">womenanim</button><br/>
<button id="flameanim">flameanim</button><br/>
```